# Find and Replace using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm trying to use Notepad++ to do some find and replace as I'm dealing with up to few thousand of lines of data.

The below is the example of the data structure that i am dealing with.

```
A = Can be any Aplabet
X = Can be any Number 0-9
RX = Number that I want to replace with another value.

AAAAA X.XXXXXX X.XXXXX X X X X X XX:XX:XX:XX.XXX XXX RXRXRXRXRXRX XXXXXX XXXXXX

Actual Example

werwer 2.178924  1.17892  1 1 1 1 1   12:14:44:59.123  123  0123123  123345  123123
gret   2.178975  1.15731  1 1 1 1 1   12:14:44:59.123  123  0123     123345  123123
sdfwe  2.123245  1.15171  1 1 1 1 1   12:14:44:59.123  123  0555312  123345  123123
```

Is there a shortcut I can use?

Comment: Will the replace string start at fixed position in a line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've set the `regex` tag, I'll post two relevant ones here.

First one matches the end of your pattern exactly:

```
^(.+ )[0-9]{6}( [0-9]{6} [0-9]{6})$
```

And the second one ignores exact lengthes of the fields and just ensures that they are numerical and in correct positions:

```
^(.+ )[0-9]+( [0-9]+ [0-9]+)$
```

The replace string would be `\1CHANGEDNUMBER\2`.

Hope that helps you more than an answer with shortcuts everyone knows.

Comment: thanks man thats what I need! so much better than the CTRL+F CTRL+H

Comment: whitequark, is it possible to replace with a random number between 300,000 - 400,000?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with Notepad++, as that is (a fairly simple) programming problem. I can write the code in [Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) or [Ruby](http://ruby-lang.org/), if you have anything of that on your computer, or can install it.

Comment: I can install either one. Can I add you in MSN ?

Comment: I don't have MSN, but you can contact me with jabber (in my profile).

Comment: added you in Gtalk should work with jabber i think